# Laravel routes, index.php, previously not required

Tags: laravel, routes, localhost

I have a project written in laravel, without any (know by me) reason, all of sudden no route but the main require index.php in the url.

e.g.- http://localhost:8080/argentinaremataNew/public/index.php/portada does work but http://localhost:8080/argentinaremataNew/public/portada does not.

The problem happens only in localhost, only in one of the projects, both projects on localhost, both uses the same .htaccess, the default of laravel

What could be wrong?

PS:
This is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Update: The error that I'm getting using the route without index.php is:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 766
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 621
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

I also have dumped the request in index.php, and in the parameters of ServerBag I found out this differences:

## DIFF

### ERROR

```
"REDIRECT_STATUS" => "200"
"HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL" => "max-age=0"
"REDIRECT_URL" => "/argentinaRemataLaravel/public/remates"
"REQUEST_URI" => "/argentinaRemataLaravel/public/remates"
"PHP_SELF" => "/ArgentinaRemataLaravel/public/index.php"
"REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT" => 1484155078.67
"REQUEST_TIME" => 1484155078
```

### OK

```
"REQUEST_URI" => "/argentinaRemataLaravel/public/index.php/remates"
"PATH_INFO" => "/remates"
"PATH_TRANSLATED" => "C:\wamp64\www\remates"
"PHP_SELF" => "/argentinaRemataLaravel/public/index.php/remates"
"REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT" => 1484155074.707
"REQUEST_TIME" => 1484155074
```

============================================================================================================================================

### ERROR

```
"REDIRECT_STATUS" => "200"
"HTTP_HOST" => "localhost"
"HTTP_CONNECTION" => "keep-alive"
"HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL" => "max-age=0"
"HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS" => "1"
"HTTP_USER_AGENT" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"
"HTTP_ACCEPT" => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
"HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" => "gzip, deflate, sdch, br"
"HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" => "es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6"
"HTTP_COOKIE" => "Phpstorm-41ab736d=2b43fb9f-e131-4096-8172-e695f536039c; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjJIUVBjcWRnd2djaFlnTFNHT1hQbUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiazRId1lNdVBGaXYzSEs1MENJbURONHRaeHVmMWJvWFR6ekFMakh3S0V1QVVhNzhXc0lpaFlnSG5oV3BcLzU5TDdWN2h3RjlcL1ZkaEQ0eHJxY1c3UUxpUT09IiwibWFjIjoiOTgyYTcwZGY4N2ExZjQ2YjlkMzViZWVjOWY1YTUxNWM5Y2E5MTkzOWNhMmJkNjQwM2RkOTA4NjA5MmU4NWYxMyJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Im1vTDlSd1ZwcitWc0dVOERYcDVSQ1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVVwvcngwallRQ0RvTE1UbXdmb2tmcTd5OVR4eDRcL2l5a3JSaTRWdlJRXC96MTNxeXQ0UGxlajZMTXVZOU9LM0xwZ0NsYjdVMnp3WXNQN1wveTFUT1FzSDF3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiI4MjRkZjI2NTRmYzY4NjU2MDAxYzE1MmQwZDlhMTU3YWE5MjFmODY4Y2FhNjA3MTFjZmQzMzQ2MzcyOWYwYmRmIn0%3D"
"PATH" => "C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;"
"SystemRoot" => "C:\Windows"
"COMSPEC" => "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"
"PATHEXT" => ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC"
"WINDIR" => "C:\Windows"
"SERVER_SIGNATURE" => "<address>Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at localhost Port 80</address>\n"
"SERVER_SOFTWARE" => "Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25"
"SERVER_NAME" => "localhost"
"SERVER_ADDR" => "::1"
"SERVER_PORT" => "80"
"REMOTE_ADDR" => "::1"
"DOCUMENT_ROOT" => "C:/wamp64/www"
"REQUEST_SCHEME" => "http"
"CONTEXT_PREFIX" => ""
"CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT" => "C:/wamp64/www"
"SERVER_ADMIN" => "wampserver@wampserver.invalid"
"SCRIPT_FILENAME" => "C:/wamp64/www/ArgentinaRemataLaravel/public/index.php"
"REMOTE_PORT" => "9812"
"REDIRECT_URL" => "/argentinaRemataLaravel/public/remates"
"GATEWAY_INTERFACE" => "CGI/1.1"
"SERVER_PROTOCOL" => "HTTP/1.1"
"REQUEST_METHOD" => "GET"
"QUERY_STRING" => ""
"REQUEST_URI" => "/argentinaRemataLaravel/public/remates"
"SCRIPT_NAME" => "/ArgentinaRemataLaravel/public/index.php"
"PHP_SELF" => "/ArgentinaRemataLaravel/public/index.php"
"REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT" => 1484155078.67
"REQUEST_TIME" => 1484155078
```

### OK

```
"HTTP_HOST" => "localhost"
"HTTP_CONNECTION" => "keep-alive"
"HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS" => "1"
"HTTP_USER_AGENT" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"
"HTTP_ACCEPT" => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
"HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" => "gzip, deflate, sdch, br"
"HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" => "es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6"
"HTTP_COOKIE" => "Phpstorm-41ab736d=2b43fb9f-e131-4096-8172-e695f536039c; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjJIUVBjcWRnd2djaFlnTFNHT1hQbUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiazRId1lNdVBGaXYzSEs1MENJbURONHRaeHVmMWJvWFR6ekFMakh3S0V1QVVhNzhXc0lpaFlnSG5oV3BcLzU5TDdWN2h3RjlcL1ZkaEQ0eHJxY1c3UUxpUT09IiwibWFjIjoiOTgyYTcwZGY4N2ExZjQ2YjlkMzViZWVjOWY1YTUxNWM5Y2E5MTkzOWNhMmJkNjQwM2RkOTA4NjA5MmU4NWYxMyJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Im1vTDlSd1ZwcitWc0dVOERYcDVSQ1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVVwvcngwallRQ0RvTE1UbXdmb2tmcTd5OVR4eDRcL2l5a3JSaTRWdlJRXC96MTNxeXQ0UGxlajZMTXVZOU9LM0xwZ0NsYjdVMnp3WXNQN1wveTFUT1FzSDF3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiI4MjRkZjI2NTRmYzY4NjU2MDAxYzE1MmQwZDlhMTU3YWE5MjFmODY4Y2FhNjA3MTFjZmQzMzQ2MzcyOWYwYmRmIn0%3D"
"PATH" => "C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;"
"SystemRoot" => "C:\Windows"
"COMSPEC" => "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"
"PATHEXT" => ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC"
"WINDIR" => "C:\Windows"
"SERVER_SIGNATURE" => "<address>Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at localhost Port 80</address>\n"
"SERVER_SOFTWARE" => "Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25"
"SERVER_NAME" => "localhost"
"SERVER_ADDR" => "::1"
"SERVER_PORT" => "80"
"REMOTE_ADDR" => "::1"
"DOCUMENT_ROOT" => "C:/wamp64/www"
"REQUEST_SCHEME" => "http"
"CONTEXT_PREFIX" => ""
"CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT" => "C:/wamp64/www"
"SERVER_ADMIN" => "wampserver@wampserver.invalid"
"SCRIPT_FILENAME" => "C:/wamp64/www/ArgentinaRemataLaravel/public/index.php"
"REMOTE_PORT" => "9812"
"GATEWAY_INTERFACE" => "CGI/1.1"
"SERVER_PROTOCOL" => "HTTP/1.1"
"REQUEST_METHOD" => "GET"
"QUERY_STRING" => ""
"REQUEST_URI" => "/argentinaRemataLaravel/public/index.php/remates"
"SCRIPT_NAME" => "/argentinaRemataLaravel/public/index.php"
"PATH_INFO" => "/remates"
"PATH_TRANSLATED" => "C:\wamp64\www\remates"
"PHP_SELF" => "/argentinaRemataLaravel/public/index.php/remates"
"REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT" => 1484155074.707
"REQUEST_TIME" => 1484155074
```

Could anybody please give me a hand on this?

Thanks :D

Comment: Do your .htaccess work or do you have enabled a2enmod rewrite?

Comment: I don't know if it works, how can I find out?

Comment: Write in it's top line deny from all . If site opens than htaccess does not work

Comment: I wrote it, error 403, so the .htaccess is working